# Difference - tf.gradients vs tf.keras.backend.gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

Being new to Tensorflow, I am trying to understand the difference between underlying functionality of tf.gradients and tf.keras.backend.gradients.

The latter finds the gradient of input feature values w.r.t cost function.

But I couldn't get a clear idea on the former whether it computes the gradient over cost function or output probabilities (For example, consider the case of binary classification using a simple feed forward network. Output probability here is referred to the Sigmoid activation outcome of final layer with single neuron. Cost is given by Binary cross entropy)

I have referred the official documentation for tf.gradients, but it is short and vague (for me), and I did not get a clear picture - The documentation mentions it as just 'y' - is it cost or output probability?

Why I need the gradients? 
To implement a basic gradient based feature attribution.

Comment: My understanding is both take the grad of a loss (or cost) function wrt parameters. The loss function is whatever you define it to be, i.e. mse between the predictions and the targets for regression or the binary cross entropy etc.

Answer (score 1):

They are basically the same. `tf.keras` is TensorFlow's high-level API for building and training deep learning models. It's used for fast prototyping, state-of-the-art research, and production. `tf.Keras` basically uses Tensorflow in its backend. By looking at `tf.Keras` source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L3772-L3784), we can see that `tf.keras.backend.gradients` indeed uses `tf.gradients`:

```py
# Part of Keras.backend.py

from tensorflow.python.ops import gradients as gradients_module

@keras_export('keras.backend.gradients')
def gradients(loss, variables):
  """Returns the gradients of `loss` w.r.t. `variables`.
  Arguments:
      loss: Scalar tensor to minimize.
      variables: List of variables.
  Returns:
      A gradients tensor.
  """
   # ========
   # Uses tensorflow's gradient function
   # ========
  return gradients_module.gradients(
      loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
```

Comment: Additionally, tf.gradients will always work on logits that probabilities. If we call Keras' tf.keras.backend.gradients with probabilities (like sigmoid activation output), it will first convert them to an equivalent logit representation and then call the underlying tf.gradients of TensorFlow. On the other hand, If we call tf.keras.backend.gradients with logits (equivalently loss here), it will in turn call tf.gradients directly.